# Does a Keras checkpointer save the best weights when using chekpoints with restore_best_weights?

Tags: keras

I m training a sequence model in Keras using the tensorflow backend.  I've also included some callbacks to save checkpoints and revert to best weights if the model starts to overfit (which it will).

My question - when fitting using this set of callbacks, does the final checkpoint contain the version of the model with the best weight?  I know that the weights in `classif_model` will revert but I'm not sure if that also applies to the final saved state.

```
from keras import callbacks as kc

classif_model = my_model(input_shape)

# Set up callbacks
checkpointer = kc.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='results/'+name+'.h5', verbose=0)
earlystopping = kc.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience, restore_best_weights = True)
callbacks = [checkpointer, earlystopping]

# train the model
hist = classif_model.fit(x = X_tr, y = Y_tr, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, 
                         callbacks = callbacks, validation_data = (X_val, Y_val), 
                         verbose = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will if you set the `save_best_only` flag in your checkpoint callback definition:

```
ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
```

From the [docs](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint):

> save_best_only: if save_best_only=True, the latest best model
>   according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.